# select error if there is no data in and clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

i have a query that fetches form details and discards formid if already assigned to some user.

```
$formIds = DB::table('tbl_staff_user_details')
          ->select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(forms_assigned) as form_ids'))
          ->first();
$formIds = array_unique(explode(",", $formIds->form_ids));
if (Input::has('form_id'))
{
     $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_forms where id IN('.Input::get('form_id').')';
}
else
{
     $lm_ids = Input::get('law_id');            
     $sql =  'SELECT *
              FROM tbl_forms
              WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.') AND id 
              NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')';
}
$data = DB::select($sql);
```

when i do `dd($formIds)` i am getting as `" "`.

and an error as:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   at line 3 (SQL: SELECT * FROM tbl_forms WHERE lm_id IN(1,2,3,4,5) AND
>   id NOT IN())

how to fire `$sql` if `$formIds` is null.

Comment: Simply put an if block if $formIds is not null then only fire the query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i want $sql to get fired if $formIds is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` the empty value:

```
$formIds = array_unique(explode(",", $formIds->form_ids));

$formIds = array_filter($formIds, function($item){
        return !empty($item);
});
if (Input::has('form_id'))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_forms where id IN('.Input::get('form_id').')';
}
else
{
     $lm_ids = Input::get('law_id');      
     if(!empty($formIds)){      
        $sql =  'SELECT *
          FROM tbl_forms
          WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.') AND id 
          NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')';
     }else{
       $sql =  'SELECT *
          FROM tbl_forms
          WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.');
     }
}
```

Comment: if $formIds is having null value then i don't want AND id NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).') clause to be part of $sql.

Answer (score 0):

> how to fire $sql if $formIds is null.

**EDIT 2:**

> i don't want `AND id NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')` clause to be part of `$sql` if `$formIds` is `null`

```
...
if($formsIds) $formIds = array_unique(explode(",", $formIds->form_ids)); // Dont forget this line

if (Input::has('form_id'))
{
     $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_forms where id IN('.Input::get('form_id').')';
}
else
{
   $lm_ids = Input::get('law_id');
   if(is_null($formIds) || empty($formIds)) {        
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_forms WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.')';
   } else {
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_forms WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.') AND id NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')';
   }

}
$data = DB::select($sql);

if($data) {
   //Handle data here
} else {
   //$data is empty
}
```

Comment: i want $sql =  'SELECT *
              FROM tbl_forms
              WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.') AND id 
              NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')';    to get fired if $formIds is null.

Comment: You are aware that `$sql` will never be null in your example? But rather it will be an empty array? Anyhow, I'll update my answer and include more code

Comment: it is showing as Undefined variable: sql in line of $data = DB::select($sql);

Comment: You can't expect from someone to write code instead of you, but I've updated my answer to include the full code now

Comment: sir please guide me as i'm new in this, i don't want AND id 
              NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).') clause to be part of  $sql if $formIds is null.

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you build your query, only add the NOT IN clause if it makes sense to do so.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
          FROM tbl_forms
          WHERE lm_id IN('.$lm_ids.')";

if ($formIds != null) {
     $sql .= ' AND id NOT IN('.join(",",$formIds).')';
}
```